# Output on Jupyter Notebook looks weird

Tags: python, jupyter

I do have a non-major issue, but hope for help here.

I user Jupyter Notebook on VS-Code and my output for simple statements looks quit weird when it prints out.
For an example a simple statement like df.info prints like in the picture attached.
[Screenshot of weird output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SDWr9.png)

Thank you all for your advise how to get my output aligned.

Best regards!

Comment: This is correct output. If you want to print out an align `df`, just use `df` instead of `df.info`.

Answer (score 1):

You should install the official Jupyter plugin on vscode. [Check this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-toolsai.jupyter).
Make sure to remove the previous one reload vscode, install the new one.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for your response. But it's still not working out. I do have the same appearance. But thanks anyways.

Comment: @AbdoCherry I see some customization on your VScode, like moving the right bar and etc. I guess it might be related to those, Can you move the VSCode back to default and retry that?

Comment: Hi, 

thanks @Sadra Naddaf. I've tried your advise but it's not getting better. 

I just want to have it to look like in Jupiter Notebook (Localhost on browser).

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and tried changing my font and it got fixed! the following fonts worked: Consolas, Courier New, and Monospace.
Monaco, Menlo, Droid Sans Mono, Inconsolata didn't work for me.